# How to load image in Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a class `photo` in parse, and 4 `imageView` in my project.

[image]

So i wanna load image from `photo` and set it to my `imageviews` with `trade_id`. 
Tell me how i can do it please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryPhoto = ParseQuery.getQuery("photo");
    queryPhoto.whereEqualTo("trade_id",trade_id);
    queryPhoto.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> listPhoto, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e == null){
                for (ParseObject photo : listPhoto){
                     ParseFile parseFile = (ParseFile)photo.get("imageFile");
                     final String imageName =photo.getString("imageName");
                     if (parseFile != null) {
                            parseFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    if (data != null && e == null) {
                                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length);
                                            if(imageName.equals("image1"))
                                                    imageVIew1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                                else if(imageName.equals("image2"))
                                                    imageVIew2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                                else if(imageName.equals("image3"))
                                                    imageVIew3.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                                else if(imageName.equals("image4"))
                                                    imageVIew4.setImageBitmap(bitmap);                                      }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                 }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: but i have 4 imageView , your code only add 1 imageView :(

Comment: you can check with imageName

Comment: i want save it to a list of bitmap

Answer (score 1):

```
@kishore jethava   is also right but you can also get url from parse then load that url into imageview with the help of any library like Glide or Picassio or even you can download the image manually from the provided url.

ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryPhoto = ParseQuery.getQuery("photo");
        queryPhoto.whereEqualTo("trade_id",trade_id);
        queryPhoto.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> listPhoto, ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(e == null){
                    for (ParseObject photo : listPhoto){
                         ParseFile parseFile = photo.getParseFile("imageFile");
                         if(parseFile!=null)
                         {
                          final String imageULr=parseFile.getUrl();
                         Glide.with(context).load(imageULr).into(imageView);
                         }
                         }
                     }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: what should i do if i have 4 image and i wanna set it to 4 imageview ?

Comment: it load only one image @@ i have 4 image same trade_id @@